# Errors when installing Caffe on Mac OS X 10.10.5

Tags: macos, matlab, caffe

I am installing caffe on my mac. I have installed all of the dependencies on my computer. I ran 'make all -j8' on the command line under the caffe directory and I encountered the following errors which I could not solve. Could anyone help me with these? (sorry, I pasted all the responses appeared on my computer so they look a little bit long. the main errors are located near the end. I don't know why there exists such many warnings and I am not sure if they really matter the installing process).

```
In file included from src/caffe/layers/crop_layer.cpp:10:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/filter_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/flatten_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hinge_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/infogain_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/input_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/log_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/lstm_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/lstm_unit_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/neuron_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/parameter_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/layers/lstm_unit_layer.cpp:6:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layers/lstm_layer.hpp:11:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.hpp:11:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/layers/power_layer.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/layers/lstm_layer.cpp:8:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layers/lstm_layer.hpp:11:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.hpp:11:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/reduction_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/reshape_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/rnn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/scale_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.cpp:8:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.hpp:11:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/split_layer.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/layers/rnn_layer.cpp:8:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layers/rnn_layer.hpp:11:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.hpp:11:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/layers/spp_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/tile_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/net.cpp
CXX src/caffe/parallel.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/adagrad_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/adam_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/nesterov_solver.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.cpp:3:
In file included from ./include/caffe/sgd_solvers.hpp:7:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/solvers/rmsprop_solver.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/solvers/adagrad_solver.cpp:3:
In file included from ./include/caffe/sgd_solvers.hpp:7:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/solvers/adam_solver.cpp:3:
In file included from ./include/caffe/sgd_solvers.hpp:7:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/syncedmem.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/solver.cpp:6:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/util/benchmark.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/solvers/nesterov_solver.cpp:3:
In file included from ./include/caffe/sgd_solvers.hpp:7:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/parallel.cpp:12:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/util/cudnn.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/solvers/rmsprop_solver.cpp:3:
In file included from ./include/caffe/sgd_solvers.hpp:7:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/util/hdf5.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/im2col.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/insert_splits.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/io.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/math_functions.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp:4:
In file included from ./include/caffe/sgd_solvers.hpp:7:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX src/caffe/util/signal_handler.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/net.cpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
src/caffe/net.cpp:571:3: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
  LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: Forward(bottom, loss) "
  ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
2 warnings generated.
CXX tools/caffe.cpp
CXX tools/compute_image_mean.cpp
CXX tools/convert_imageset.cpp
CXX tools/device_query.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/util/signal_handler.cpp:7:
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/signal_handler.h:5:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX tools/extract_features.cpp
CXX tools/finetune_net.cpp
CXX tools/net_speed_benchmark.cpp
CXX tools/test_net.cpp
CXX tools/train_net.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp:6:
In file included from ./include/caffe/parallel.hpp:13:
In file included from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp:50:7: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
      LOG_EVERY_N(INFO, 1000)<< log_on_wait;
      ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
2 warnings generated.
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp
In file included from tools/finetune_net.cpp:1:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from tools/caffe.cpp:15:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.cpp
CXX examples/cifar10/convert_cifar_data.cpp
In file included from tools/extract_features.cpp:9:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp
In file included from tools/test_net.cpp:1:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.cpp
In file included from tools/net_speed_benchmark.cpp:1:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX examples/siamese/convert_mnist_siamese_data.cpp
In file included from tools/train_net.cpp:1:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
In file included from tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp:10:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp:10:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.cpp:10:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:1:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:917:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:912:73: note: expanded from macro 'GOOGLE_GLOG_COMPILE_ASSERT'
  typedef google::glog_internal_namespace_::CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: library not found for -lippicv
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_conv_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_lcn_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_lrn_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_pooling_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_relu_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_softmax_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_tanh_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn.o) has no symbols
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors were finally solved. Many thanks to the inspiration from @Prune.

Actually the clang warning was not something that caused this compile process to be stopped. The compile process was stopped because I modified those brew formulas recommended on Caffe website (details see http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html). In my case, I am using Mac with OS X 10.10.5, and employ CPU-use only, thus using original brew install formulas are OK.

The clang warnings and GLOG warnings are trivial on OS X so we don't have to pay too much attention to. If you wanna remove warnings on '-pthread', one way is to remove '`-pthread`' flags from CXXFLAGS and LINKFLAGS in the 'Makefile'. For details see this thread https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3608

Answer (score 1):

Caffe's **make** file and source files are built for a variety of platforms.  Many of the features apply to only one class of platform.  To keep the script easier to read and maintain, the non-fatal items are allowed to appear in the processed source code.  This results in warnings for unused identifiers.

You can ignore these.  I have yet to find one that I needed for my installation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed '-pthread' flag in the CXXFLAGS and LINKFLAGS in the Makefile, and compiled with cmake and it works now.

Comment: Glad you got it solved.  Please post the solution as an answer and accept it, so that SO can properly archive the question.  If you prefer, edit my answer, or include it in yours.